# How to catch exception in future in play framework 2.4

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to figure out how to catch an exception from within a future in a function being called by an asynchronous action in Play Framework 2.4. However, the code I've got using recover never seems to get executed - I always get an Execution exception page rather than an Ok response.

The action code is:

```
def index = Action.async {
    cardRepo.getAll()
    .map {
      cards => Ok(views.html.cardlist(cards))
    }.recover{
      case e: Exception => Ok(e.getMessage)
    }
  }
```

The code in cardRepo.getAll (that I've hard-coded a throw new Exception for experimenting) is:

```
def getAll(): Future[Seq[Card]] = {

    implicit val cardFormat = Json.format[Card]

    val cards = collection.find(Json.obj())
      .cursor[Card]()
      .collect[Seq]()

    throw new Exception("OH DEAR")

    cards
  }
```

I've seen similar questions on Stack Overflow but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your exception example is incorrect. Exception in not thrown from within `Future`, but from within method `getAll`, so `map` function on `future` is never invoked. Replace body of `getAll` with: `Future.failed(new RuntimeException)`.

Comment: And btw, don't define implicits in a function. It is a waste of resource. :-) Move it to `Card` companion object.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mon Calamari - I think I understand now. The future is coming from collection.find, so if an error was inside that, my code would work but because I've put I've got it inside the function above it, there is no Future at that point.